# Putting two apps in one

Tags: android

I currently have two apps that I use for calculations on a daily basis and I would like to combine them into one app with an option to choose between both of them. Does anybody know how to approach this? Thank you.

**I am using android studio

Comment: So you want a third app that launches the other two? If not, simply merge the code of the two apps. There's no easy way to do that

Comment: You can have more than one launcher activity in a project.  But I would only recommend this if the two activities share a substantial amount of code and you don't want to maintain that shared code as a separate library project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create new android project and integrate you two project files within the new one and then create a `MainActivity` for new project that gives option to choose which application to run, then start one of mainActivity of the two app based on user choice. (by using [startActivity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) method)